# Select a specific number from a row in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to select a SQL Query for only "09xxxxxxxxx" from below table :

```
021-77083709 - 09125800327

09123301673 22514057

09121964217 09332712035
```

Its might be anywhere in the row and I want to select these numbers. This mean "09" + 9 character after that.

For Example in overhead rows, select these numbers :

09125800327

09123301673

09121964217

09332712035

**My Table**
http://upload.tehran98.com/upme/uploads/33a59e81d6d51d311.jpg

Thanks

Comment: can you also share your table structure please?

Comment: Are you saying you want to select 4 results from 3 rows?  If so, do you really need to do this entirely in SQL Server?

Comment: why you want to do this in sql server? it's easier to do it on vb or c# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you part of the way there...

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(tbl.columnName,
                  PATINDEX('%09[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',
                           tbl.ColumnName), 11) FirstOccurrance
FROM    TableName tbl
WHERE   tbl.columnName LIKE '%09[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

This will only extract the first occurrence of the pattern within a column, 
also the pattern matching is pretty limited.

By the way in your example is 09 + 9 characters not 10

Here is a function that can be used to extract all matching values in a column as a csv string

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FilterValues
    (
      @OriginalValue NVARCHAR(2000)
    )
RETURNS NVARCHAR(2000)
AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @IDX INT = PATINDEX('%09[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',
                                    @OriginalValue);
        DECLARE @Temp NVARCHAR(4000) = @OriginalValue;
        DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(4000) = '';

        WHILE ( @IDX IS NOT NULL
                AND @IDX > 0
              ) 
            BEGIN
                SET @Result = @Result + SUBSTRING(@Temp, @IDX, 11);
                SET @Temp = SUBSTRING(@Temp, @IDX + 11, LEN(@Temp) - 11);
                SET @IDX = PATINDEX('%09[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',
                                    @Temp);
                IF ( @IDX IS NOT NULL
                     AND @IDX > 0
                   ) 
                    BEGIN
                        SET @Result = @Result + ',';
                    END

            END

        RETURN @Result;
    END
```

Here is an example on how to use the query with the function

```
SELECT  dbo.FilterValues(tbl.ColumnName) MatchedValues
FROM    TableName tbl
WHERE   tbl.columnName LIKE '%09[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

Comment: If its possible would you please say something about this code ? What is SUBSTRING and PATINDEX used for ? any resources for learning it ?

Comment: @user3101948 PATINDEX and SUBSTRING are built in string functions for SQL.  PATINDEX (PatternIndex) returns the index (character position) within the string for the first match of the pattern specified.  SUBSTRING returns part of a given string based on a starting index (character position) and length (number of characters to retrieve).  You can read the documentation on all available string functions here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984(v=SQL.105).aspx

Comment: @user3101948 You can also learn more about the pattern matching in provided for the PATINDEX and LIKE operators here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859(v=sql.105).aspx